# How to change dynamically APP_KEY in for different different users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

Basically i want to assign different different APP_KEY to different different user i have stored generated app_key in "users table" so, my question is how can i achieve this? i have try but can't get proper solution

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => Auth::User()->APP_KEY

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the message from exception ?

Comment: I was thinking, **what is the use case of having a different `APP_KEY` for users?**

Comment: yes, i want this

Comment: This is really bad idea because this key is application wide and you must change framework behavior in many places

Answer (score 1):

you can create one middleware, and inside of handle method change config value...

```php
class SetConfig
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


        config()->set("app.key", Auth::User()->APP_KEY);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and need to init middleware on `App\Http\Kernel` like this:

```php
 protected $middleware = [
          ...
          SetConfig::class,
          ...
    ];
```

or
on provider :

```php
        $router = $this->app['router'];

        $router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('web', SetConfig::class);
```

Comment: thanks ali ! how can i use this ? by group Middleware?

Comment: Route::get('{pro_name}/login-user', [CustomAuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login-user')->middleware('setconfig');

Comment: config()->set("app.key", 'base64:c3Ti/BcIvegI57GUGo4E7i0ieanGMZa6+PfDUROpfKQ=');

Comment: i have make Middleware and add this all logic but it is not working

Comment: Illuminate\Encryption\MissingAppKeyException
No application encryption key has been specified.

Comment: you should check `APP_KEY` not null , set default value . `Auth::User()->APP_KEY ?? 'default_value'`

Comment: if you want use in route, you should define in `$routeMiddleware`. @sarimali

Comment: config()->set("app.key", Auth::User()->APP_KEY); i am using this function but they are not set APP_KEY they only pick in env file default key